# Unifying predictions from the same model but with differing assumptions

Tags: modeling, assumptions, uncertainty

I'm working with the same dataset and I'm exploring several approaches to modelize it. Each model applies the same model but operates under different assumptions, such as:

- Stationarity vs. Non-stationarity
- Log-transformed vs. Non-log-transformed data
- Clustered vs. Non-clustered extremes

Given these variations, each model naturally yields different point predictions, since they operate on different transformations of that dataset. I'm seeking advice on how to systematically quantify and possibly integrate these divergent predictions into a unified predictive framework. Thank you.